# How to change to a StringBuilder in java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to change the following code to `StringBuilder` so I can format the output of an `ArrayList` how can I do this.

```
 private static String createFormattedList(List<List<String>> failureList) {
    String lineBreak = "</br>";
    String result = "";
    for (List<String> failure : failureList) {

        for (String item : failure) {
            result += item + lineBreak;
        }
        result += lineBreak;

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: We can do that with many ways few are listed below:

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
private static String createFormattedList(List<List<String>> failureList) {
    String lineBreak = "</br>";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (List<String> failure : failureList) {
        for (String item : failure) {
            result.append(item).append(lineBreak);
        }
        result.append(lineBreak);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```